# Adding JDK 8 to Eclipse on mac

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to experiment with lambda expressions in Java 8 but I need to update my jdk from 7 to 8. When I download the jdk and install from the .dmg I'm unable to find it in my files to change the build path. How do I get JDK 8 into my eclipse build path?

Comment: What does `java -version` in terminal show?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click project -> Build Path -> Configure build path -> add library -> jre system library -> alternate jre -> installed jres -> search -> select the one you want -> click ok -> in previous window (alternate jre), select the one u just picked.